# Split command without separator

Tags: python, split, sum

I would like to make a program that adds a 3 digit number together but I cannot get python to run a split command without entering a separator. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
a, b, c = input("x=").split("")
a, b, c, = int(a), int(b), int(c)
print(a+b+c)
```

Comment: I'm not clear what the issue is? Are you trying to split it into a list of characters?

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that sums a three digit number together eg.) 123 = 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is exactly three caracters, this would work:

```
a, b, c = input("x=")
print sum([int(i) for i in [a,b,c]])
```

althought, for a more flexible option:

```
user_input = input("x=")
print sum([int(c) for c in user_input])
```

**** Beware that on python 2, this won't work, you have to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. I'm assuming you're using python 3?

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why I don't have to split the string?

Comment: Could you explain why you would need it? You can check each character in strings with loops: `for c in text: print c`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this ?

```
sum(int(c) for c in input("x="))
```

Or if you want to delete the `split("")` from your code, just run this :

```
a, b, c = list(input("x="))
a, b, c, = int(a), int(b), int(c)
print(a+b+c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you input the number as integer, then you need to convert it to string first. Equivalent of empty separator is convert string to a list.

```
a, b, c = list(str(input("x=")))
```

If you input in the form of string, then `str` call is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the input to one variable, and use a list comprehension to split it up into digits. Then simply use the sum function.

```
number = input("x=")
digits = [int(dig) for dig in number]
print(sum(digits))
```

Or in a single line:

```
print(sum([int(digit) for digit in input("x=")]))
```

Answer (score 0):

well when you give 3 verbals `a, b, c = input("x=")` you have to enter list of numbers like `[1,2,3]`and no need to split them it will go to each,

but if you want to sum all the number, since you can't predict how many number will be entered, you better get all the value as string then split them to integer:

```
value = str(input("x="))
numSum = 0
for eachvalue in value:
    numSum = numSum + int(eachvalue)
print(numSum)
```

**Edit:**
also if the person enter string like `'sdf2324'` you can check if what it's entered is Integer by just simply adding this in the code:

```
if eachvalue in "1234567890":
```

so you final code will be:

```
value = str(input("x="))
numSum = 0
for eachvalue in value:
    if eachvalue in "1234567890":
        numSum = numSum + int(eachvalue)
print(numSum)
```